# Node Mysql not inserting

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var url = require('url');

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var aluno, disc;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log("aluno: " + req.query.aluno);
  console.log("disc: " + request.query.disc);

});

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host: "localhost",
 user: "root",
 password: "161616",
 database: "matricula"
});

connection.connect();

var post = {idDisciplinasMatriculada: aluno*3+disc*2, idDisciplina: disc, idAluno: aluno};

connection.query('INSERT INTO DisciplinasMatriculadas SET ?', post, function(err, result) {});
```

When I change a few things I can run it throught CMD receiving args, but when it receives a "/index.js?aluno=2&disc=2" from the browser, nothing happens at the DB.

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Also, here is the HTML file that I'm using:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DisciplinasMatriculadas</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: sans-serif">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Matricula de aluno em disciplina</legend>
            ID Aluno: <input type="text" name="aluno" id="aluno">
            <br/>
            ID Disciplina: <input type="text" name="disc" id="disc">
            <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addDisciplina();">
        </fieldset>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    function addDisciplina(){
    var alunold = $('#aluno').val();
    var discold = $('#disc').val();
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:80/node/index.js",
        data: { aluno: alunold, disc: discold}
        })
        .success(function(data){alert('Done.');})
        .error(function(x,q,h){});
    };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well this sorta has a combination of insert syntax combined with update syntax (with the `SET`) unless I am missing something. In other words, when is the word `SET` ever used in an Insert stmt (other than an IODKU call)

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders can only represent VALUES. They cannot replace sql keywords, field names, table names, operators etc... Values only. Your query must be something more like

```
INSERT ... SET fieldname = ?
```

While not exactly true, consider a placeholder the equivalent of a string literal. Your version is generating what amounts to:

```
INSERT ... SET 'fieldname=?'
```

That's not assignment operation. It's a string with the characters `f`, `i`, `e` etc... Where should this string be put in the record? There's no field to assign to, so it's a syntax error.

Comment: Changed for, but no difference :(

var x = disc+aluno*2;
var post = {x,disc,aluno};

connection.query('INSERT INTO DisciplinasMatriculadas(idDisciplinasMatriculada,idDisciplina, idAluno) VALUES (?,?,?)', post, function(err, result) {});